# Проблема с wifi на arch

Tags: linux, wifi, archlinux

При попытке запуска wifi в лог начнаeт спамиться ошибка:

```
[  883.571469] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  883.571472] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:9d1b] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  883.571475] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Так же начинает очень сильно гудеть кулер.Пробовал по [этой](https://forum.altlinux.org/index.php?topic=41532.0) инстуркции добавить pci=nomsi/pci=noneau, но результата 0.
Ноутбук: HP-15au041ur,

Comment: на всякий, понимаешь, что конфиг/команда обновления grub'а у тебя не те, что в альте? хорошо бы привести в подтверждение `cat /proc/cmdline`, что всё правильно сделал...

Comment: [Здесь](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) просто указана точно такая же команда. `cat /proc/cmdline,` вернула `initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda3 rw`. Тогда как можно обновить grub?

Comment: вписать `pci=nomsi` в `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` в `/etc/default/grub`, а затем выполнить команду, указанную в шапке файла (`update-grub-что-то-там возможно куда-то >перенаправить`)... знак того, что всё правильно сделал — после перезагрузке в `cat /proc/cmdline` появится это самое `pci=nomsi`...

Comment: В шапке не нашёл другой команды [Текст файла](https://pastebin.com/sWf0tPta)

Comment: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, не забудь примонтировать `/boot`, если он на отдельном разделе... все дистрибутивы, что я видел обычно включают комментарий об этом в шапку конфига... странно, что arch так не сделал...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо огромное, пофиксил